# Jackson: passing exta objects during deserialization

Tags: java, jackson

During deserialization, how can I pass in an extra object that's needed to initialize some class member? If I were doing deserialization "manually," the implementation might look like:

```
public class MyClass {

    private MyDocumentObject do;
    private String food;

    public MyClass(JsonNode node, MyDocument document) {
        this.do = document.createMyDocumentObject();
        this.food = node.get("food").asText();
    }

    public String getFood() {
        return this.food;
    }

}
```

But I'd like to use Jackson's automatic mapping facilities and use a decorated constructor or custom deserializer, etc. and avoid implementing the deserialization within the class itself. Looking at example implementations using `@JsonCreator` or extending `StdDeserializer`, I can't see a way of saying "hey, please use this `MyDocument` object when you call the constructor." I'd like to *avoid* implementing and exposing a separate method that accepts a `MyDocument` that I have to invoke on every object that gets deserialized, e.g.

```
public createDocumentObject(MyDocument document) {
    this.do = document.createMyDocumentObject();
}
```

I don't want to have this method at all, but if I had to, I'd want Jackson to call this method for me right after deserialization. That means I'd still have to somehow tell Jackson which `MyDocument` to use.

Comment: How about: All your classes extends a common abstract class which has `MyDocumentObject`, and you declare a custom Deserializer for your abstract class ?

Comment: I don't see what benefit the abstract class is for this issue, but I guess there's a very simple solution actually, just add the `MyDocument` in the constructor of the deserializer: ```ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
module.addDeserializer(MyClass.class, new MyClassDeserializer(document));
mapper.registerModule(module);```